# How to make Progressbar and ads static(unmovable) in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

In an Activity which contains 3 fragments, i have implemented auto-hide toolbar function. It works well but, i want to make my progressbar unmovable(currently it goes up as i scroll the page) the same for adview. How do i proceed?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:isScrollContainer="false"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
android:clipToPadding="false"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout

xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dip"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/greenprogress"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />

<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webViewTop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/progressBar3"/>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

I know that they both are in `NestedScrollView`, but if i contain `NestedScrollView` around webview like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dip"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/greenprogress"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webViewTop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/progressBar3"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

adview appears to be static. And progress disappears altogether(Appears on screen for 1 sec then gone).

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Solved it. Created a Linear layout and moved webview and progress-bar in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dip"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/greenprogress"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webViewTop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/progressBar3"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>


<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```